# How can I move my block to the right side of the page using justify-content

Tags: html, css, justify

My Justify-content isn't working.I wanted to move the block of codes to the right end of the page, but instead it went to the left side. What went wrong? What can I do? Are there any alternatives or do I have to use justify content?Please Help me!
Here are the codes of my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    </head>
    
    <!--Body-->
    <body>
        <div class="container_1">
            <div class="box_1">
                <h3>Box One</h3>
                <p>Random Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box_2">
                <h3>Box Two</h3>
                <p>Random Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box_3">
                <h3>Box Three</h3>
                <p>Random Text</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>

        <div class="container_2">
            <div class="box_4">
                <h3>Box Four</h3>
                <p>Random Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box_5">
                <h3>Box Five</h3>
                <p>Random Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box_6">
                <h3>Box Six</h3>
                <p>Random Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the CSS codes:

```
.container_1 {
    display: flex;


}

.box_1{
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
        /*flex*/
    flex: 1;

}


.box_2{
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
        /*flex*/
    flex: 3;

}


.box_3{

    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
            /*flex*/
    flex: 1;
   
}

.container_2 {
    display:flex;
    width: 10%;
    **justify-content: flex-end;**

}

.box_4{
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
        /*flex*/
    flex: 1;

}


.box_5{
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
        /*flex*/
    flex: 1;
    

}


.box_6{

    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
            /*flex*/
    flex: 1;
   
}
```

Comment: which boxes do you mean? what your desired result? can you tell us?

Comment: the boxes in container_2@Dev

Comment: and what do you want to achive? can you describe it to me?

Comment: So this?  - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZEyBZOM

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i want @Paulie_D, what have I done wrong

Comment: You told the children to expand as much as possible and then restricted the overall width to 10%

Comment: oh so flex expands as much as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.container_2` to this:

```css
.container_2 {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    /* removed width: 10% */
}
```

and remove `flex: 1` from your boxes.

#### Description:

`flex: 1` makes the item grow in the container as much as there's free space.